# How can a photon exist on its own without a mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, photons, mass

For example, thermal energy exists and has no mass, but is carried by particles which have mass. A photon is described as a particle - how can a photon exist on its own, travel in space and even push other particles with mass if it has no mass itself?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos I am not asking about momentum

Comment: The relationship to energy is given in the proposed duplicate; the relationship to momentum (which allows it to "push" other particles) is also discussed.

Comment: Photons don't have rest mass. Neither does thermal energy. There are, of course, no resting photons and the thermal energy of resting particles is zero. No contradiction.

Comment: What we talk about mass in modern physics is rest mass. Photons never have a "rest" , you can't "catch up with " it and "measure" its mass.